# It's + plural noun

Tags: grammar, pronouns

Please consider the following sentences:
1. I want you to know that IT'S the decisions you should make.
2. I want you to know that THEY ARE the decisions you should make.

which one is the more natural?

Comment: I don't really know what you mean by either (1) or (2). So I would say neither one is a very good English sentence.

Answer (score 2):

This is a matter of usage rather than numerical agreement.

With “it’s the decisions”, the word *decisions* is used in the abstract. It doesn’t refer to any particular decision.

When you say “they’re the decisions”, the word *decisions* refers to a specific set of decisions.

So “it’s the decisions you should make” is an exhortation to make decisions, while “they’re the decisions you should make” urges the adoption of a specific set of decisions.

Comment: Thanks lawrence. But I often find IT IS followed by a plural noun, especially when it bears the sense of "that" or "this", like: who is that? IT IS us. I really want to holistically understand this usage.

Comment: In “it is us”, “is” has to agree with “it”, not “us”. In “X verb Y”, normally the verb would need to agree with X.

Comment: Yeah I know, but what is the reason for using IT for the plural noun US? The exact reason?

Comment: @FadliSheikh It depends on the context. Sometimes *it* is used as a dummy subject (like *it is raining*). Sometimes it’s because a preceding question asked for something in the singular (e.g. “What *was* under the bed?” “*It was* kittens”), etc.

Comment: I see. You really are an expert, Lawrence. Thanks a lot. By the way, can we say "it" is sometimes a counterpart of "that/those/this/these"?

Comment: @FadliSheikh That's very kind of you, and you're welcome. You might want to ask a separate question about that. "That/those/this/these" are called [demonstratives](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/determiners/this-that-these-those) - like a finger pointing to whatever the word refers to. "It" doesn't quite have that quality, except *maybe* in an abstract sense when "it" is used as a dummy subject.

Answer (score 0):

Sentence (1) is wrong. "it" will only be followed by a plural noun in cleft sentences (where emphasis is sought), for example:

3. I want you to know that **it's** your decisions that count.

Sentence (2) sounds strange because the pronoun "they" is not sufficiently deictic, that is, it does not clearly point to the referent. A plural demonstrative would fit in much better:

4. I want you to know that **these / those** (the ones you have mentioned / the ones that have been proposed) **are** the decisions you should make.

Comment: I am not sure I agree with this. What the OP appears to want to say is that "it is the decisions (and not the actions/arguments etc) that you should make". In other words it is a "cleft sentence" and your example (3) is the one applicable, not (4).

Comment: @WS2 I see your point. There is ambiguity as to whether "(that) you should make" is a relative clause or the second part of a cleft sentence. I felt inclined to interpret it as a relative because the verb "make" will not easily accept other abstract nouns like "decisions", at least within the context of the given sentence.

Comment: If the "that" clause is a "cleft sentence," it can be restated, albeit less effectively, as "... that you should make the decisions." If that's what the OP means, then "It's" is the right word.  If, however, the OP means @Gustavson (4), then "they are" is correct, but with his proposed fix ("these" or "those"). Let's ask the asker...

Comment: Guys, thanks for your various answers. Actually, I just want to know whether IT IS may be followed by a plural noun to that extent because I often find IT IS followed by a plural noun when the noun is regarded as a group, like the following: A: Who is knocking at the door? B: IT IS them. We all know the phrase "THEY ARE them" here would be completely ungrammatical, neither would it sound logical, but why? Would anyone provide me with one simple explanation of this matter?