# Why do we say “it’s (singular) days (plural) like these (plural)”?

Tags: grammar, grammatical-number, it-its-itself

Is it because what we’re saying is: it is days like this one, and all others like it, that collectively (followed by 3rd person plural verb form)?

Comment: Because it's an idiom. Subject _it_, when not pointing to something non-human, is normally part of an idiom. Don't expect it to follow agreement rules.

Comment: Not many people would use plural ***these*** in the cited context anyway. Most of us (particularly, *Brits*) say [*It's days like **this...***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=It%27s+days+like+this%2CIt%27s+days+like+these&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) But I suppose ***these*** might make more sense if, for example, ***yesterday*** shared the same contextually relevant attributes as today (with the expectation that ***tomorrow*** would be the same).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [It's + plural noun](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/487901/its-plural-noun) Or perhaps better [use of here's before a plural noun/ noun phrase](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/359055/use-of-heres-before-a-plural-noun-noun-phrase). Here's / It's use the sentence-delaying device in a number-transparent way 'It's us' has been mentioned many times on ELU. It are / Here're would be awful.

Comment: Could you please post what you mean??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider a sentence like this one:

> It is days like these that always prove most difficult.

In this sentence, the word *it* isn't acting as an ordinary referential pronoun; it doesn't refer to the "days" or to anything else. Instead, it's part of a construction known as an ***it*-cleft.** In this construction, the singular pronoun *it* is used as the subject of *to be,* so *to be* has to be singular in form. But this pronoun is just a placeholder; it stands in for something defined by the relative clause at the end of the sentence, which is equivalent in meaning to "The *x* such that *x* always prove most difficult = these days."

(My source for the above is Huddleston & Pullum (2002), pp. 1414-1420.)

Answer (score 2):

**It's** is a dummy pronoun contracted with the verb *is*. In situations where English syntax demands a subject but there aren't better options for a subject, *it* can act non-referentially to jump-start the sentence. For instance, in

> It is raining

nothing specific is being referred to as raining. That is just how we express a state of weather: it's idiomatic.

The dummy pronoun is used with several kinds of statements, including those referring to time (["Dummy Pronouns," *Lund University*](https://www.awelu.lu.se/language/selective-mini-grammar/pronouns/dummy-pronouns/)). *It's* can be followed by a singular or plural verb, e.g.,

> It's a year I'll never forget.

> It's 5 minutes I'll never get back.

As for *days like this [day]* versus *days like these [days]*, the choice depends on whether you are thinking of one specific day or an indeterminate series of days. You could use either, as [Ngram results illustrate](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=It%27s%20days%20like%20this%2CIt%27s%20days%20like%20these&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3):

> It's days like this ...

> It's days like these ...